# Two different expression for electric field of electric dipole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, dipole-moment

According to Tamilnadu textbook,

> The electric field due to an electric dipole at a point on the equatorial line is
>   $$E = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{p}{r^3}$$
>   As shown below, the direction of E is along PR, parallel to the axis of the dipole and directed opposite to the direction of dipole moment.
>   [image]

However, in the NCERT book it says

> At a point on the equatorial plane ($r \gg a$)
>   $$\mathbf{E} = - \frac{\mathbf{p}}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^3}$$
>   [image: Image as in NCERT book]

The two have different signs. Which one is correct?

Comment: Can't they *both* correct? One is clearly discussing a *magnitude* while the other is clearly discussing a *vector*, so they're both right, *in the appropriate limits*, no?

Comment: @KyleKanos Post this as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NCERT formula is correct if used with vector notation as the direction of electric dipole moment is from 
-q(negative charge) to +q(positive charge) and the resultant electric field at any point on equatorial line is 
in direction opposite to the electric dipole moment so negative sign is used.
The other formula which does not include negative sign is applicable to calculate the magnitude(not direction)
 of electric field.

Comment: You can tell the first formula is only referring to the magnitude because the $E$ on the right hand side does not have an arrow above it (as in $\vec{E}$), nor is it bold (as in $\mathbf{E}$). These are two ways of showing something is supposed to refer to a vector. The plain ordinary $E$ just denotes the magnitude of the electric field.

Answer (score 1):

Both the equations are correct.

In the case of the tamilnadu textbook, the electric field magnitude is given along the equatorial line. Since we take the direction of dipole moment from negative to positive (taking distance of separation as a vector directed from negative to positive), the electric field is directed in the opposite direction.

Ncert states this mathematically with the negative sign that electric field is directed in the opposite direction.